# Convention when creating helper functions in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create a function `dropColumnIfExists` to be used in laravel migrations, I've found the following code online.

```php
function myDropColumnIfExists($myTable, $column)
{
    if (Schema::hasColumn($myTable, $column)) //check the column
    {
        Schema::table($myTable, function (Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->dropColumn($column); //drop it
        });
    }

}
```

I want to know what's the convention on where this helper function should be placed (inside a class or standalone / in which file) and how best to import it.

secondly, intelephense is giving me errors about Schema not being found. should I pass the Schema to the function when running it or is there once again a convention to go by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Schema Bleuprint](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Schema/Blueprint.php#L17) is macroable, it means you can extend and add you own functions

So for example you can create your own service provider (ex: `CustomSchemaServiceProvider`) and [register it](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/providers#registering-providers).

I created the code and test it on my local and it works as expected, you can twik since you get the idea ;)

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
class CustomSchemaServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Blueprint::macro('dropColumnIfExists', function (string $column) {
            if (Schema::hasColumn($this->getTable(), $column)) //check the column
            {
                $this->dropColumn($column); //drop it
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Try now on your migration file: ex:

```php
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::table('tableName', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumnIfExists('columnName');
        });
    }
```